# Partition Reconfiguring in Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a Stateful service fabric application. In the application Parameter file i have PartitionCount as 20

When i deploy service to the cluster I get 20 partitions and some of the partition status is showing as "Reconfiguring" and finally they are going to warning state showing Unhealthy evnet

> Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.FM', Property='State',
>   HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false. Partition
>   reconfiguration is taking longer than expected.

But the replica health inside that Partition is showing as "OK"

What is actually happening when partition is in "Reconfiguring" state ?
Why this error occurs?

Comment: Are there any messages from ETW? To try and diagnose and debug, run on your local development cluster with just 1 partition and make sure that works. Then try locally with 2 partitions and make sure it works ok.  If this is the case, it could be that 20 partitions may be too many for the cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reconfiguration of a stateful service is when Service Fabric is shuffling replicas around the cluster. This occurs any time the system needs to make a change to replica placement, which can be fail-over to ensure availability of replicas during machine down time or upgrades, or for resource balancing to ensure workloads are balanced across the cluster - the latter occurs immediately when you deploy a new service, as the system has to find a place to put the replicas and then balance everything out.

If reconfiguration is taking longer then expected, there's a good chance a replica is either not responding to a change role or close action (e.g., your service code is not responding to the cancellation token in RunAsync), or a replica is failing to start (e.g., your communication listener code throws an exception on OpenAsync).

Comment: My application is working fine in Local cluster without any warnings. Is this because the Local cluster has no reconfiguration process or Could it be something related to the public cluster ?

Comment: Local clusters are no different from a cluster you deploy in Azure or anywhere else, except that all the nodes are running on one machine. It's an issue with your service, that could be environment-related. For example, make sure there is adequate disk space on the nodes in the cluster to which you are deploying. You need at least 8 GB of free space on each node for stateful services. For example, DS-series VMs in Azure have very small local disks, which can be a problem for stateful services.

Comment: On further investigation i found that OpenAsync was failing sometimes because Simple Injector was not configured specifically for Owin, These links helped me : http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html

http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/owinintegration.html